# overflow auto not working when i shrink the screen

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css, overflow

In div(parent div) i set 7-8 div  and set parent div overflow auto, i set width 100%  it working for full screen but when i shrinking screen or for table screen its not working , how to resolve that issue without setting hard code width ...

i want overflow-auto property should work for every screen ,my code look like that..
i'm using tailwind css

```
<div className="flex w-[100%] overflow-auto ">
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
 <div>4</div>
 <div>5</div>
 <div>6</div>
 <div>7</div>
 <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided code functions correctly across all screen sizes. For additional details and comprehensive documentation on the overflow utility, please refer to the official Tailwind CSS documentation available at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overflow.